# HTML, CSS, JS responsive dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive

First, I'd like to apologize for my mistakes in grammar.
My problem is that I made a responsive dropdown menu in HTML with CSS and with JavaScript, but when I make the webpage smaller than 600px, everything works except the dropdown part. It shows all the main parts of the menu, here there are "Kezdőlap", "Rajzok", "Festmények" etc. But it does not show "Fekete-fehér grafikák" and so all. So, the `ul` > `li` > `ul` > `li` parts that I mean. When it is smaller than 600px width.

I have to make this code better, to show everything. So, here is the HTML part:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Kezdőlap</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="rajzok.html"><span>Rajzok</span></a>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="rajzok.html">Fekete-fehér grafikák</a></li>
                <li><a href="szinesrajzok.html">Színes képek</a></li>
                <li><a href="negative.html">Negatív rajzok</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="festmenyek.html"><span>Festmények</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="festmenyek.html">Fekete-fehér</a></li>
                <li><a href="szinesfestmenyek.html">Színes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="kapcs.html">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                <li><a href="insp.html">Inspiráció</a></li>
                <li><a href="other.html">Egyéb alkotások</a></li>
                <li class="ikon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have a CSS code (it is not the full, but I guess you can understand my problem) which looks like this:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    nav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    nav li.ikon {float: right; display: inline-block;}
    nav ul.kibont {position: relative;}
    nav ul.kibont li.ikon {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;}
    nav ul.kibont li {float: none; display: block;}
    nav ul.kibont li a {display: block; text-align: left;} 
}
```

and the JS:

```
function myFunction()
{
     document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0].classList.toggle("kibont");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding any `li` that isn't first in the list with

```
nav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
```

So you'll need to change that if you want the other `li`s to show.

Comment: If I change it to display: block or delete this line, it will show all the li-s in the main first level, but I dont want to do that but I would like to show the second ul's li-s inside the li-s. do you understand me?

Comment: You can create a css rule like `nav li.hidden-small { display: none; }` inside of your media query and then just put the `hidden-small` class on whatever you want to hide.

Comment: my problem is when it shows all the li-s inside the first ul, I just cant choose between the sub-menus, because it only shows the main parts...

Comment: Sorry, it is too vague.  If you can update your question with more detail on what you want, or even a jsfiddle, that would help

Comment: Okay, then, tomorrow I will upload everything and a video as well, to show my problem. Thank you so much!